# Suppress "never useful" precedence warning in modular parser specifications?

Tags: ocaml, menhir

Is it possible to suppress unused precedence warnings in menhir?

Background:

I have a core parser `Lib.mly` with several rules and, separately, a host of additional parsers (`A.mly`, `B.mly`, ...) which use definitions from `Lib.mly`.  To support using a single lexer for all the languages, all tokens are defined in `Lib.mly` and we use `external_tokens(Lib)` annotations in `_tags` and have extended `myocamlbuild.ml` to suppress unused tokens warnings with `--unused-tokens` which helps significantly.  However, I still get many warnings of the form:

```
File "parsers/ParserLib.mly", line 126, characters 0-9:                     
Warning: the precedence level assigned to FIX is never useful.
```

These make it hard to see other warnings I actually want to address. Different subsets of the operators are used in various languages, so I need to have a single "global" precedence that orders them appropriately.  Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, Menhir has a new option `--unused-precedence-levels`.

If you have examples of grammars that are split over several files, I might be interested to look at them (and possibly include some of them in Menhir's test suite, if permitted).

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you very much for the support and for making menhir such a stellar tool. Our parsers are not yet public, but I will check with my colleagues and send you a tarball.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're searching for but the two following options may be useful :

```
--unused-token <token>           Do not warn that <token> is unused
--unused-tokens                  Do not warn about any unused token
```

Comment: Yes, those have been helpful for avoiding the unused token warnings.  Unfortunately, they don't seem to turn off the "precedence never useful" warnings for said unused tokens :\  I think the next step is filing a menhir issue and just using awk to filter unwanted warnings for now, but ugh.